# Accessing Users File users.xml in Clickhouse Docker Container?

Tags: database, docker, permissions, clickhouse

I am working my way through learning to use docker and have set up a docker container in my host machine for clickhouse utilizing local storage volumes on port 8123.

https://hub.docker.com/r/yandex/clickhouse-server/

I am interested now in editing my users.xml file to create access permissions. I am still relatively new to docker. How would I go about accessing this file in the container?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you run `clickhouse-server` you can exec into that container and can view/edit any files in it.

- Once you run `clickhouse-server` docker container. Run `docker ps` and get the container-id.
- Run `docker exec -it container-id bash` Running this you will enter into the bash shell of that container.
- In bash shell you can view/edit any files, in this case your `users.xml` is located here `/etc/clickhouse-server/users.xml`

  OR

You can also create docker image with the edited `users.xml` file. Using `dockerfile`.

*dockerfile*

```
FROM yandex/clickhouse-server
COPY users.xml /etc/clickhouse-server/users.xml
```

`users.xml` file with updated contents.

Now create docker image using `docker build -t myimage:v1 .`

Run docker container `docker run -itd myimage:v1` This will run the container with updated users.xml.

For more info around working with docker, please check [this](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/) out.

Comment: Instead of editing `users.xml` you can just create a separate file like `extra_users.xml` and copy it to `/etc/clickhouse-server/users.d/`. In this file you describe all extra users settings. This file will work together with `users.xml`.